# Calling a javascript function in another javascript file just work in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two javascript files:

func1.js:

```
function HelloWorld() {  
   alert("hi");
}
```

func2.js:

```
function btnclick(){
    $.getScript("func1.js", function () {          
        HelloWorld();  
    });
}
```

My HTML code is :

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="javasvript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javasvript" type="text/javascript" src="func2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick()" value="Click me" />
</body>
</html>
```

when I click on the button call `btnclick()` function and in `btnclick`() function load `func1.js` and call a `Helloworld()` function .

but this is work fine just in mozila .
Don't work in chrome and IE.
How can i solve it ?

Comment: Your code:  `language="javasvript"`... there is no such thing as `javasvript`.  And `src="jquey.js"` will be broken if you're really trying to reference a file called `jquery.js`.

Comment: jquery.js is also spelled wrong, i guess

Comment: What JavaScript console errors are you getting?  My guess is that Mozilla is simply ignoring your botched `language` attribute.

Comment: @Sparky I change `language="javasvript"` to `language="javascript"` .but don't work. and `jquery.js` name is correct .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact that you are not giving enough details, you should consider fixing the typos in your code.

I assume that if your code works in mozzila and it doesn´t work in chrome that is because you are trying to run it offline.

Mozzila can take ajax requests offline, chrome doesn´t, so please try again by running it on a server after you have all the typos fixed.

Comment: You don't see anything wrong with `language="javasvript"` or `src="jquey.js"`?  And "same origin" policy does not restrict to _local_ server... it restricts to _same_ server/domain/site.

Comment: I assumed that "jquey" actually contains jquery since the alert worked. I did not see the  typo in the script tag but again fixing just that will not solve his problem. The error he has is that he is not running this on a localhost.

Comment: How do you know what error he has when he hasn't told us? And that is NOT what the error in your answer says... read it again... your interpretation is 100% incorrect.

Comment: I replicated his exact code locally, no server running, that´s the error I get. If you run it on a server it should work.

Comment: Your error simply says that it looked for the file locally and could not find it.  Then it goes on to say:  "Cross origin requests are ***only supported for protocol schemes***: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."  ~  That does NOT mean only local server!  The OP also never stated or implied he was running it locally.

Comment: What is your point?  Your test server is not considered a "local" server... that's not what "local" means.

Comment: My point is that if you run that on a server (local or not) the code works, if you just open the file "offline" chrome will throw that cross origin request error. It´s not because of the typo or the way he named his jquery file. If my answer is not adressing the problem correctly please consider deleting it, I will back you up.

Comment: _"My point is that if you run that on a server (local or not) the code works"_  ~ That's true but the OP never stated how he was running it, nor if any errors are being reported.

Comment: I don't believe the OP has given us enough information to know the problem.  And I can only submit a vote to delete your answer, however you can immediately delete (or fix) it without me.

Comment: I assumed it because I knew that mozzila can take ajax requests offline, chrome doesn´t, so for me it wasn´t necessary to have that specified.

Comment: Then all of that should have been explained in your answer along with relevant sources backing up any claims.  IMO, it's a leap when the OP never stated his error message or what kind of server he was using.  It's always best to _very clearly_ explain your answer so people can learn.

Comment: @hermaneduard thanks for answer . but I cant solve it . do you have an idea for do this in local ?

Answer (score 0):

You just have some syntax errors:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="func1.js"></script>
<script <!-- this does not exist: language="javasvript"--> type="text/javascript" src="func2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="btnclick()" value="Click me" />
</body>
</html>
```

And you don't need to use $.getScript, just call the function:

```
function btnclick(){         
        HelloWorld();  
}
```

As the function is global, to call a function in a script1 from script2 the only requisite is to load the script1 before script2

Comment: I do'nt want add script func1.js to the html code . I want load it by `$.getScript` in `func2.js`